# Removing single quotes when writing dict to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been searching for hours and can't find an answer to what should be a very simple question.

I have a dict...

```
{'apples' : 'red', 'pears' : 'green', 'bananas' : 'yellow'}
```

When I try to write this to a CSV, it keeps the single quotes and they end up in my file... which I do not want.

```
outputz = {}
print('\nBegin phrase token output:\n')
    with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                dialect='excel', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='/')

        spamwriter.writerow([outputz])
        spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
        writer = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'w'))
        for key, value in outputz.items():
               writer.writerow([key, value])
    outputz = {}
else:
    outputz = {}
```

I don't want to re-tool or rewrite the entire code, since you can see I'm already leaning on tutorial examples. I'm not looking to be a full time developer, I just need to knock this out once for my boss.

How do I, in Python 3, write my dict to 2 columns (key, value) of a csv without the stupid brackets and single quotes. Can someone give me an example code?

Comment: Your code sample makes little sense. What's with the indentation? Where is `outputz` defined? Why the `else:` block at the end without a matching `if`, `for`, `while` or `try` statement?

Comment: Why do you open the CSV file *twice*, first writing the whole dictionary, then re-opening it (clearing it) to write just te dictionary items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a lot of issues, but it looks like your basic problem is that you're writing the whole dictionary at once (`spamwriter.writerow([outputz])`), rather than item by item. If you want the output in `(key, value)` columns, then that's precisely what you should do: for each key-value pair, write that pair to the csv file. You're actually doing this already, with lines ten and eleven of the code you posted:

```
import csv
outputz = {'apples' : 'red', 'pears' : 'green', 'bananas' : 'yellow'}
with open(r'C:\test\foo.bar', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in outputz.items(): # Iterate over the dictionary items
        writer.writerow([key, value]) # Write each pair to the csv file.
```

This code produces the expected key-value pairs in the output file when I run it.

---

I suggest that you clean up your code a little: you've got some crazy indentation and some weird stuff going on that I suspect is the real root of your problem. Your third line appears to be indented for no reason, and you've got a very suspicious `else` clause hanging around. **Finally, you're opening the output file twice** (on lines three and nine), which I suspect could be the true culprit in this little situation.